# The difference between an existing solution and an IoT solution?

Tags: iot

I'm trying to understand how IoT could help the company that I'm working for. This company provides software and hardware to others - take, for example, printers.

We already build and deploy software on the printers which have the ability to report back information (somewhere) so that management can react to certain data points:

- Printer ink levels
- Printer status (working, jammed, off, on, etc)
- Printer state (good, errored, etc)

What would an IoT solution do for this type of situation?

As I understand it, IoT is mainly all about data and how we can analyze the data coming in from a fleet of devices.

Some things I've thought might be beneficial:

1. Instead of sending just "Printer Ink Low" and "Printer Ink Empty", continuously send the raw printer ink levels somewhere where you can analyze the average rates of printer ink use. You can then use that data to preemptively refill the ink.
2. Separation of concerns - software around the printer ink or printing process should be separate from the reporting aspect of the printer ink levels.
3. Similar to #1, sending raw data to be processed/learned upon to somewhere else is beneficial, as processing the data is moved from the device (which should focus on printing) to somewhere else (the cloud, a local compute server).
4. This collected data can be used to analyze trends and make business decisions.
5. This collected data can be used to preemptively act on situations instead of reactively (increasing efficiency).

Other questions:

1. As I understand IoT, it is usually a physical device or sensor that can connect to the Internet (either itself or through another device) and send up data. It *usually* is a physical device, but can it be more of a *software* device? IE a docker module that monitors the system and reports data? Would that be considered an IoT solution/device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, stackoverflow is not the right place for such open questions (I would suggest other fora, like, e.g., researchgate), in general, the answer to all your questions, is yes, you are on the right way.
Especially for your last question, you have to have some kind of hardware (e.g., an extra or existing ink level meter inside the printer). All those hardware devices that interact with the environment and monitor something (temp, humidity, salt in water) are the sensors. Behind the sensors, you can have any kind of software/cloud/program/other hardware (e.g., raspberry/arduino), to implement your specific needs.